# Removing trailing spaces in all lines from a input file to spring batch program

Tags: java, file, spaces, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program which reads from a file and writes to a database.

Data is delimited by || (double pipes) and there is no delimiter at end of line.

```
one||two||three||four
foo||bar||foo1||bar1
```

Issue is the end of each line is having hundreds of trailing spaces before end of line character.

Using ctrl + Q, I in text pad shows:

```
one||two||three||four.......................................
foo||bar||foo1||bar1...............
car||bike||tango||charlie..........................
```

This is throwing parsing error at each line in ItemReader (org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader)

I can not remove the spaces manually and need some automation so that before the file is read by spring batch program, the spaces are gone.

How to do this ?

Note: The error occurs only when I run the program over unix server. It does not happen on windows.

```
<beans:bean id="myBufferedReaderFactory" class="com.mypackage.MyBufferedReaderFactory"/>

<beans:bean id="FileToDBItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
                 <beans:property name="BufferedReaderFactory" ref="myBufferedReaderFactory"/>
        <beans:property name="resource" ref="MyInputFileResource" />
        <beans:property name="lineMapper">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <beans:bean class="com.mypackage.MyCustomLineTokenizer">
                        <beans:property name="delimiter" value="||"/>
                        <beans:property name="names" value="one,two,three,four" />
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="com.mypackage.MyFieldSetMapper" />
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Progressed a bit. But still not hitting the answer.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.BufferedReaderFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;


public class MyBufferedReaderFactory implements BufferedReaderFactory {


    public BufferedReader create(final Resource resource, final String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

        InputStream sourceStream = null;
        sourceStream = resource.getInputStream();

        //code to remove trailing spaces end

        //code to remove trailing spaces start

        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sourceStream, encoding));

    }

}
```

How can I remove the trailing spaces using InputStream object in above class ??
Thanks for reading!!

Comment: @Pratik: As mentioned, I am using spring-batch FlatFileItemReader class which uses DefaultLineMapper to map the lines which uses LineTokenizer to create tokens which map to file column names!!

Comment: I don't know about this but if you paste the code here then for other is to easy to solve the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `BufferedReader` by implementing `BufferedReaderFactory` and add line-trimming functionality to the reader. See [FlatFileItemReader.setBufferedReaderFactory()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setBufferedReaderFactory%28org.springframework.batch.item.file.BufferedReaderFactory%29).

```
public class LineTrimmingBufferedReader extends BufferedReader
{
    public LineTrimmingBufferedReader(Reader in)
    {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException
    {
        String result = super.readLine();
        return result != null ? result.trim() : null;
    }
}
```

Implement proper trailing space trimming of the line if `String.trim()` isn't acceptable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more!! <beans:property name="BufferedReaderFactory" ref="myBufferedReaderFactory" />    now ??

Comment: Can you please check the question. Added code related to BufferedReaderFactory

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
BufferedReader reader = ....
String line = null;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replaceAll("\\s*$");
    // do what you need with the line
}
```

If you have some automatic procedure that reads files and inserts everything to DB and you cannot modify the procedure, create code that reads files and removes trailing spaces (as shown above) and writes the trimmed lines to other file. This other file can be an input for your DB import procedure.

BTW if you are using linux you can just say:

cat myfile.txt | sed 's/ *$//' > mytrimmedfile.txt

(probably you have to escape `*` in this statement)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Replace the DefaultLineMapper in configuration with following custom class DefaultTrimmingLineMapper.

```
public class DefaultTrimmingLineMapper<T> extends DefaultLineMapper<T> {

    /** 
     * Trims the line before passing it to the {@link DefaultLineMapper}.
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper#mapLine(java.lang.String, int)
     */
    @Override
    public T mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        return super.mapLine(line!=null?line.trim():null, lineNumber);
    }
}
```